# redirect function or directive in .htaccess for redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

is there a simple sophisticyated way to hide a url-part (f.e. /subdirectory/index.php -> https://www.domain.com/index.php) in .htaccess or similar?
I have heard that this could be done by redirecting. I am nosey if this .htaccess file is the proper location for this directive?
Please some examples are requested. thanks

Comment: @anubhava: simple: (in a word) I would like to hide a part of the URL (not the Domain part!) I have found this: [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/03/podcast-63-the-plumbers-up-to-67-coins/?cb=1) Would YOU mind telling me some examples? I can not think on some.

Comment: Ok in the meantime I could handle the problem myself!